# symfony 3 and FOSRest Bundle Routing

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, symfony-routing

I am trying to setup the symfony3 codebase with FOS REST Bundle and I end up getting no route found error

AppBundle\Resources\config\api-routing.yml

```yaml
check:
    type: rest
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/CheckController.php"
```

app\config\routing.yml

```yaml
app:
    type: rest
    prefix: /
    resource: '@AppBundle/Resources/config/api-routing.yml'
```

controller

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Version;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\RouteResource;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * @RouteResource("Check")
 * @Version("v1")
 */

class CheckController extends FOSRestController
{

    public function getAction(Request $request)
    {
        $data = "Ok";
        return new JsonResponse($data);
    }
}

http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/app/check/ return no route
```

I would like to integrate the versioning of rest api route. Can you share what cud be the error and how can I correct this ?

```yaml
fos_rest:
    body_listener: true
    versioning:
        enabled: true
        resolvers:
            query: 
                enabled: true
                parameter_name: version
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            json: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working example.

app\config\routng.yml

```
app:
    type: rest
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix: /api
```

AppBundle\Resources\config\routing.yml

```
rest_my:
    type: rest
    prefix: /v1
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/MyRestController.php"
    name_prefix:  api_1_
```

Active route will be:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/<MyRestControllerAction>
```

or for second controller

AppBundle\Resources\config\routing.yml

```
rest_user:
    type: rest
    prefix: /v1/user
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/UserRestController.php"
    name_prefix:  api_1_
```

Active route will be:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/user/<UserRestControllerAction>
```

I hope I help you... Chears.

**Update #1:**
Here is my complete fos_rest configuration for json format into config.yml file:

```
fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
        include_format: false
    body_converter:
        enabled: true
    body_listener:
        decoders:
            json: fos_rest.decoder.json
    format_listener:
        enabled: true
        rules:
            - { path: '^/api/v1/', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: true}
            - { path: '^/', priorities: ['json', 'html'], fallback_format: 'html' }
    serializer:
        serialize_null: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        templating_formats:
            html: false
    param_fetcher_listener: 'force'
```

If you need more then that you have full documentation for fos_rest
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/configuration-reference.html

Comment: can you share your fos config setting. I updated with mine.

Comment: Also I am trying leverage versioning provided by FOSRest bundle

Comment: when I debug route I do see /v1/app/check but when I am trying to load on webpage http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/app/check It say route not found.....I have defined getAction() in Checkcontroller...Do you think my method mapping is correct?

Comment: In example need to track prefix route
Create getExampleAction into controller and try to go on 127.0.0.1:8000/v1/app/example route

Comment: The issue is with @Version of FOSRestBundle without it I think adding /v1 as prefix does work.